# installing ubuntu-restricted-addons from script

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management

I have a post-install script I use to install a few packages after a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation.

One of these packages is `ubuntu-restricted-addons`. I wold like to be able to install this package unattended - i.e.: without having to `OK` the license.

Is there a way to add something to the script to accept the license automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

Comment: How do I implement this inside a bash script?

Comment: Just add that text verbatim (or if you're already root in it, remove the `sudo`)

Comment: sorry it took me a while, but I use dselact to install additional packages via a regular text file containing a package name and "install" per line. Should I prefix the line containing the ubuntu-restricted-addons with the argument you suggested?

Comment: @PenguinCSC Can you edit details of exactly which commands you're running into your question?